# Add a column by matching id from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I would like to ask for help!

I am trying to add a new column "TotalSasaran" to my first dataframe 'dataset' with 5000 rows

| Tangal | Divaksin1 | Divaksin2 | Total Divaksin | Provinsi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2-1-2021 | 1 | 2 | 3 | Aceh |
| 5-1-2021 | 1 | 2 | 3 | Aceh |
| 2-1-2021 | 2 | 2 | 3 | Bali |
| 4-1-2021 | 2 | 2 | 3 | Bali |
| 3-1-201 | 3 | 1 | 4 | Jakarta |
| 6-1-201 | 3 | 1 | 4 | Jakarta |

```
structure(list(tanggal = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2021-01-15", 
"2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-20", "2021-01-21", 
"2021-01-22", "2021-01-23", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-26", 
"2021-01-27", "2021-01-28", "2021-01-29", "2021-01-30", "2021-01-31", 
"2021-02-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-03", "2021-02-04", "2021-02-05", 
"2021-02-06", "2021-02-07", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-09", "2021-02-10", 
"2021-02-11", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-13", "2021-02-14", "2021-02-15", 
"2021-02-16", "2021-02-17", "2021-02-18", "2021-02-19", "2021-02-20", 
"2021-02-21", "2021-02-22", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-24", "2021-02-25", 
"2021-02-26", "2021-02-27", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-02", 
"2021-03-03", "2021-03-04", "2021-03-05", "2021-03-06", "2021-03-07", 
"2021-03-08", "2021-03-09", "2021-03-10", "2021-03-11", "2021-03-12", 
"2021-03-13", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-16", "2021-03-17", 
"2021-03-18", "2021-03-19", "2021-03-20", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-22", 
"2021-03-23", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", 
"2021-03-28", "2021-03-29", "2021-03-30", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-04-02", "2021-04-03", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-05", "2021-04-06", 
"2021-04-07", "2021-04-08", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-10", "2021-04-11", 
"2021-04-12", "2021-04-13", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-15", "2021-04-16", 
"2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", 
"2021-04-22", "2021-04-23", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", 
"2021-04-27", "2021-04-28", "2021-04-29", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-01", 
"2021-05-02", "2021-05-03", "2021-05-04", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-06", 
"2021-05-07", "2021-05-08", "2021-05-09", "2021-05-10", "2021-05-11", 
"2021-05-12", "2021-05-13", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-17", "2021-05-18", 
"2021-05-19", "2021-05-20", "2021-05-21", "2021-05-22", "2021-05-23", 
"2021-05-24", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", "2021-05-27", "2021-05-28", 
"2021-05-29", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", 
"2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", 
"2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", 
"2021-01-16", "2021-05-15", "2021-05-16"), class = "factor"), 
    divaksin_1 = c(35, 1, 13, 16, 36, 42), divaksin_2 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), total_divaksin = c(35, 1, 13, 16, 36, 42), 
    Provinsi = c("Aceh", "Aceh", "Aceh", "Aceh", "Aceh", "Aceh"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

based on the value in my second df 'Total_Sasaran' with only 34 rows.

| Provinsi | Total Sasaran |
| --- | --- |
| Aceh | 1000 |
| Bali | 1500 |
| Jakarta | 2000 |

```
structure(list(Provinsi = c("ACEH", "BALI", "BANTEN", "BENGKULU", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "GORONTALO"), TotalSasaran = c(3898726, 2860037, 
8838393, 1327824, 8815157, 784727)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Both dataframes have an id column "Provinsi". I am hoping R could identify the dataset$Provinsi and match with Total_Sasaran$Provinsi to get the TotalSasaran value for each row in dataset.

I tried several code but did not return the expected output
1st code trial

```
dataset$TotalSasaran<-Total_Sasaran$TotalSasaran[match(dataset$Provinsi,Total_Sasaran$Provinsi)]
```

2nd code:

```
dataset$TotalSasaran <- Total_Sasaran$TotalSasaran[Total_Sasaran$Provinsi %in% dataset$Provinsi]
```

3rd code:

```
dataset2<-inner_join(dataset,Total_Sasaran, by="Provinsi")
```

This returns 0 observations no data were in the dataframe, I have made sure that the classes were matching, 'Provinsi' as factors and the 'TotalSasaran' as numeric

4th

```
dataset2<-merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran, by="Provinsi", all.x=TRUE)
```

This returns the whole 'TotalSasaran' column as NA

Comment: Try `inner_join` from `dplyr` packge

Comment: I did try using inner_join:
`dataset2<-merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran[, c("Provinsi", "TotalSasaran")], by="Provinsi", all.x=TRUE)`
`dataset2<-merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran, by="Provinsi", all.x=TRUE)`
but it returns the column 'TotalSasaran' as NA.

Is something wrong?
I made sure all the classes were matched.

Comment: Have you tried `merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran)` ?

Comment: Yes I did,

`dataset2<-merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran[, c("Provinsi", "TotalSasaran")], by="Provinsi", all.x=TRUE)`

`dataset2<-merge(dataset, Total_Sasaran, by="Provinsi", all.x=TRUE)`

But it sadly returned the column as NA...

Comment: Does the `Provinsi` column in `dataset` match exactly with that of `Total_Sasaran` ? Does it have any whitespace in them? You can remove the whitespace with `trimws`. It would be easier to help if you provide `dput(head(dataset))` and `dput(head(Total_Sasaran[, c("Provinsi", "TotalSasaran")]))`

Comment: The names should matched exactly, meaning that the 34 variables in Total_Sasaran$Provinsi are repeated several times in dataset$Provinsi (thus the difference in rows). I tried to update the post with the `dput()` outcome. I'm new here, I hope that was what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases of both the data is not same, one is upper-case and another one is lower case. R is case-sensitive, so either change one of the dataframe and then do `merge`.

```
df1$Provinsi <- toupper(df1$Provinsi)
result <- merge(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't know that it would be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem to address is that the "Provinsi" in the two `data.frame` do not have any matching values: in 1. you have `Aceh` in 2. you have `ACEH`. They are not the same case.

You can either convert the `Aceh` in `dataset` to upper

```
dataset$Provinsi = toupper(dataset$Provinsi)
```

or convert `ACEH` etc in `Total_Saran` to title case or sentence case (https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html):

```
library(stringr)
Total_Saran = Total_Saran%>%
 mutate(Provinsi =  str_to_title(Provinsi))
```

Don't do both! Then join the two with `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

df3 = left_join(dataset,Total_Saran)
```